# How do I create a new column to an existing data frame which is the product of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data estimating what kind of food is used on a daily basis at school to feed kids.

```
Pizza   Apples  Lemonade  Lemon   Banana  Milk  Soup
 12        3       10       1      9      10     6
 14        5       8        0      13     11     7
 ....................................................
```

I want to create a new variable `Fruits_total` which is a sum of variables `Apples`, `Lemon`, and `Banana`, and add it to an existing data frame.

```
  df['Fruits_total'] = df.Apples + df.Lemon + df.Banana
```

However, it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You code worked perfectly for me. Your error is not here.

Answer (score 4):

Use the below code

```
df['Fruits_total'] = df[['Apples','Lemon','Banana']].sum(axis=1)
```

axis = 1, shows that you are summing up the rows. This is what you missed in your code.

Comment: if you like the solution, please accept it